# dlerror:cuDevicePrimaryCtxSetFlags not found

Tags: python

I have installed tensorflow, but when I write `sess=tf.Session()` this error is returned

```
could not find cuDevicePrimaryCtxSetFlags in libcuda DSO;dlerror:cuDevicePrimaryCtxSetFlags not found
```